# What Does ".closeopen" method of TFIBDataset Component Do?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, fibplus

I am using FIB Plus components with Delphi 2010, just would like to know what `closeopen(true)` does. I tried googling but didn't get info on it.

```
FIBDataSet.closeopen(true);
```

Comment: Does this component not have any documentation?

Comment: Some how the documentation is not popping up. So I need to find out out side.

Comment: If you are on a Vista+ OS, you will need a special installation from microsoft in order to open an old help file. If you want to download the help file, http://www.devrace.com/en/fibplus/download/

Comment: I am using Windows 8 OS, would this help file work on it ?

Comment: Very difficult to know why you wouldn't look in the documentation. Please don't take the fact that Valentine looked in the documentation for you as encouragement to use Stack Overflow as a documentation viewing service.

Comment: @VishalTiwari, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/917607. What is stopping you from testing if the help file opens or not? The OS will tell you what to do.

Comment: @David: Please don't get me wrong. I tried a lot and when I didn't get then I asked. I don't practice to ask for documentation.

Comment: So your next step is to make sure you can read the documentation. I think you've got what you need. Do please feel free to carry on asking questions, but perhaps not along the lines of this one.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

procedure CloseOpen(const DoFetchAll:boolean);
This method reopen TpFIBDataSet. DoFetchAll parameter specifies whether to do a full fetch of data.

This quote  is  from russian version of document "FIbPlus 6.4 Appendix.PDF "
Unfortunately I can not find a link to the English version of the document;

Comment: Thank You so much. It would really going to help me a lot. That's great.